# FileMode is not a member of IO

Tags: vb.net

I for the first time is trying a code in VB.This code is handed over to me from my old team who codes in VB.While seeing the code i am getting an error as `FileMode is not a member of io`.Rest of the codes are fine .
Here is the line of code in which i am getting error..

```
 stamper = New iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfStamper(pReader, New System.IO.FileStream(DestinationFile, IO.FileMode.Create))
```

And i have imported `Imports System.IO` in start of the program also.

Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you imported `System.IO` all you need is:

```
stamper = New iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfStamper(pReader, New FileStream(DestinationFile, FileMode.Create))
```

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem may be that your are providing a *partial* reference to `FileMode`. For example, your code says:

```
IO.FileMode.Create
```

However, for `FileStream`, you are providing the entire namespace reference:

```
System.IO.FileStream
```

So, try this:

```
stamper = New iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfStamper(pReader, New System.IO.FileStream(DestinationFile, System.IO.FileMode.Create))
```

In the above code, note that I added `System.` before `IO.FileMode.Create))`.

I also think that, since you are using `Imports System.IO` at the top of your code (as you mentioned), you could probably just refer to both `FileStream` and `FileMode` on their own, without providing the entire namespace.